# inside the class do you assign the value to the property or the backing field

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following in a class (that extends MVVMLight's ViewModelBase):

```
private ObservableCollection<Merchant> merchants;

public ObservableCollection<Merchant> Merchants
{
    get { return merchants; }
    set { Set(nameof(Merchants), ref merchants, value); }
}
```

Inside my class, should I initialize the value of the property or the backing field? And in the methods of my class should I use the property or the backing field?

I am just learning and I tend to use both, and I don't see any difference.

Simply put: inside the class, should i use the property or its backing field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do.

When your property raises `PropertyChanged` it is a good idea to use the property setter instead of the backing field, even from within your class, so consumers get notified of the changed value.

There is one exception though: Inside your constructor, you would use the backing field, because at that time no consumer could possibly have subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event, so raising the event from the constructor is not necessary.

If you have other logic in your setter - like validation - you *always* should use the property setter instead of the backing field.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the property. This way when you add logic to the getter or setter (say, validation) you won't have to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the `get; set;` is to grant a controlled level of access to the 'backing field' from classes that may, otherwise, not have visibility of it.

With that in mind, you can assume the get or set will, and quite often does, have it's own logic for when other classes are to access the backing field's value or set it in a particular way. You may or may not want this class (the class that owns the backing field) to invoke the custom getter/setter and there lies your answer as to what property you should refer to.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a property with both getter and setter, use the automatic property with the following syntax:

```
public ObservableCollection<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }
```

In case you have to restrict the access to one of them, do it like in the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<Merchant> Merchants { get; private set; }
```

The only cause to use private backing field is either when it's *readonly*, and then you will initialize it in the constructor, or in case you have some additional logic on setting the property value (like, when implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged*).

Also, using the property access is much more refactoring-friendly.

Bottom line: use property setter, unless it is an immutable (readonly) field or you want to circumvent the property's setter logic.

Comment: With c#6, you can now use read-only properties too. "Welcome to the world of tomorrow!"